# How to compile open source framework in Visual Studio C++, that has "makefile" only and no solution file?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, makefile

How to compile open source framework in Visual Studio C++, that has "makefile" only and no solution file?

Comment: No one giving answer feels this question should be up voted. Strange.

Comment: Perhaps they don't find the question all that interesting. I answer quite a lot of questions that don't really interest me, to gain rep, be generally helpful and sometimes as a kind of penance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no silver bullet for this kind of change. Make and Visual Studio C++ style build are very different beasts.  While they can do very similar operations, they can also have wildly different structures which makes providing a simple guide very difficult.

IMHO, the best way to achieve this is to start a new C++ project.  Add in all of the existing files and go through the make file step by step attempting to convert every action to the equivalent C++ action.

Answer (score 2):

If all you need is a self-built binary that you can link to with VC (i.e. no integration into existing VS solution) then have a look at [MSys](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSYS). It allows you to use GNU make together with VC. So you can use the GNU build system delivered with the OS project, while compiling with VC.

Answer (score 2):

First make sure that the code can run on Windows. Open-source C++ code often depends on POSIX. If that is the case then you'll need to install MinGW or Cygwin.

If you are not familiar with cross-platform programming, then this project may be a painful task. (EDIT: This is speaking from my own personal experience. I do not intend to discourage you. Btw, it's the painful projects that you learn most from!)

Answer (score 1):

Why not look on this as a chance to learn some new techologies, such as [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/), which should have few problems compiling the code.

Answer (score 1):

If you intend to continue to support multiple platforms you might consider moving to a cross-platform build system like [cmake](http://www.cmake.org) or [waf](http://code.google.com/p/waf/).

Answer (score 0):

MSVC supports its own flavour of the make utility thru nmake, but there are several differences vs the GNU make (ie. see [Use the same makefile for make (Linux) and nmake(Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270391/use-the-same-makefile-for-make-linux-and-nmakewindows)).

So you may need to edit the makefile (several compiler & linker options wont apply to start with).