# C++ Make File Issue

Tags: c++, makefile

Trying to create my first makefile for a C++ program I have, but whenever I try running my makefile on my VS2015 developer command prompt using the command "nmake -f makefile.exe" I get fatal error: U1077.

```
all:
    g++ proj1.cpp -o proj1
```

Comment: What happens if you just execute the command directly. `g++ proj1.cpp -o proj1`. The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dt309377.aspx) indicates that this code means `The given command or program called by NMAKE failed and returned the given exit code.`

Comment: I get that g++ is not recognized as an internal or external command.

Comment: Okay on cygwin it runs fine when I just execute the direct command but not in my makefile.

Answer (score 0):

Garrett,

nmake and make are different tools and have a different syntax that they understand. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270391/use-the-same-makefile-for-make-linux-and-nmakewindows) for more information.

Comment: I can't click on the link and when I try to use just make it says it's not recognized.

Comment: make is the gnu tool for project files basically. It's a scripting language that can do some fairly awesome stuff if your familiar with it. The nmake that msvc provides is the 'Microsoft' flavor of make so that you can do basically the same things with the windows build system. They don't understand each other at all. The syntax in your file that you've got is for gnu make. not nmake. g++ is the gnu c++ compiler. It's found on almost every linux distribution and even on windows with the MinGW-w64 compiler tool chain. The Microsoft cpp compiler is cc.exe if my memory serves me right.

Comment: Okay so I'm trying to use Cygwin to run my makefile again.

I get: 

$ make -f makefile
make: makefile: No such file or directory
g++     makefile.cpp   -o makefile
makefile.cpp:1:4: error: found ‘:’ in nested-name-specifier, expected ‘::’
 all:
    ^
makefile.cpp:1:1: error: ‘all’ does not name a type
 all:
 ^
make: *** [<builtin>: makefile] Error 1

Comment: post your makefile.cpp for me please

Comment: `all:
 g++ proj1.cpp -o proj1`

Comment: Your missing a : in your cpp file somewhere, probably at a std::object like std::cout << "hello makefile" << std::endl; line or some thing like that. namespaces are accessed with the :: operator, and in one of those places your using only a single : . and remove the all: from your makefile. That should clear up all of your errors. I'd personally only have one line in your makefile and that would be g++ -std=c++11 -s -O3 -o proj1 proj1.cpp