# Can we use NMAKE.EXE as a substitute for GNU Make?

Tags: windows, makefile, compilation, gnu-make, nmake

I was curious to see if I can compile [this repo](https://github.com/Oblomov/clinfo), with the [Microsoft Program Maintenance Utility (NMAKE.EXE)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/nmake-reference?view=vs-2019) ([location](https://superuser.com/a/1558698/588662)) where I got the [U1001 error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/nmake-fatal-error-u1001?view=vs-2019):

> makefile(4) : fatal error U1001: syntax error : illegal character '.' in macro
>   Stop.

so I am wondering if `nmake.exe` is by any means a substitute for GNU Make?

my questions are:

- Can we have cross-compatible `Makefile`s by using a subset of shared syntax between the two?
- Can we use some sort of NMake or GNU Make macros to have compatible `MakeFile`s?
- What are the major syntax differences between NMake and GNU Make?

**P.S.** It seems that [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8270391/4999991) is very relevant to my question, if not a duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot use `nmake` as a replacement for GNU make.

If your GNU make makefile is written strictly to POSIX specification and doesn't use any GNU-specific enhancements, then you could use any POSIX-conforming instance of make with that makefile.

However, (a) it's unlikely the makefile is really POSIX-conforming, and (b) `nmake` (as far as I'm aware) isn't a POSIX-conforming implementation of make anyway.